# Ember template not displaying attributes in route js file

Tags: ember.js

Ok, am pretty confused here.

I have the following route at dashboard.info. I know the template is correlated with this route because actions such as 'submit' are fully functional.

```
// dashboard/info.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({

    testContent: "hey what's up",

    actions: {
        submit() {
            //blah blah blah 
        } 
    },
});
```

For some reason though, these attributes like testContent aren't showing up on my template:

```
//dashboard/info.hbs
<p>Should be here: {{testContent}}</p>
```

Seems so simple! I am confused. Maybe this isn't enough info. Here's something that might be relevant, I am loading in this 'form-nav' component, which in turn contains several 'panel' components containing my inputs.

```
<form {{action "submit" on="submit"}}>
  {{info.form-nav model=model}}
</form>
```

Could I be confusing Ember with too many nested components in the route? Could it be because I am not instantiating a controller? I thought Ember was trying to move away from controllers...

Lmk if I can include any more relevant info. Will be watching. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be an another way, As if you want to define your variables in "routes/dashboard/info.js" and want to use in "templates/dashboard/info.hbs". Than you can use "setupController" hook and set the "testContent". After settting it can be easily used in your "templates/dashboard/info.hbs".

```
// dashboard/info.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({

testContent: "hey what's up",
setupController: function(controller) {
    //you can set route variable to controller variable like in below so that it can be easily available in template for rendering purpose
    controller.set('testContent', this.get("testContent");

        this._super(controller, model);
    }
    actions: {
        submit() {
            //blah blah blah 
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: Awesome thank you Jyoti, this was the code I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Although Ember is trying to move away from controllers, they aren't gone yet. If you want `testContent` to appear in your `templates/dashboard/info.hbs` template, it will need to go in your `controllers/dashboard/info.js` controller.